# How to implement simple ZeroMQ Pub-Sub communication between Python publisher and C++ subscriber?

Tags: python, c++, zeromq

I am new to ZMQ, and trying to implement a simple Pub-Sub communication between Python publisher and C++ subscriber. Following the official documentation I come up with these code:

Python Publisher

```
import zmq
import datetime

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    nowInMicroseconds = str(now.microsecond)
    socket.send_string(nowInMicroseconds)
    print("sending time in microseconds")
```

C++ Subscriber

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
    subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "");

    while(true) {   
        std::cout << "Getting data" << std::endl;
        zmq::message_t update;
        subscriber.recv(&update);
        std::cout << "Data received" << std::endl;

    }
}
```

But when I run the codes, I  won't receive any data from Python. What I am doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

Running Python Publisher with Python Subscriber as `user3666197` suggested works just fine. Running C++ Publisher with C++ Subscriber works like charm.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, let's isolate the problem:

Create also another subscriber to **`.connect()`**, in python:

```
import zmq
import datetime

pass;      Pcontext = zmq.Context()
Psocket  = Pcontext.socket( zmq.SUB )

Psocket.connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555" )

Psocket.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER,     0 )
Psocket.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )
Psocket.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE,   1 )

while True:
    print( "{1:}:: Py has got this [[[{0:}]]]".format( Psocket.recv(),
                                                       str( datetime.datetime.now()
                                                            )
                                                       )
            )
```

If this works as expected, the problem is not on the sender side.
If this fails, may check a proper subscription string-handling issues on different platforms ( expecting **`u''`** on Py 3+ ).

Comment: Using your python code it works as expected, the "Py has got this" with the sent value is written to the console.

Comment: **Q.E.D.** -- the problem is in the very subscription-matching issue. So either C++ delivers a unicode-formatted string to python, or opt to have both sides using the same string-convention. Also may have noticed, that initial ZeroMQ API versions were running SUB-side topic-filtering, deciding on the delivered message on the SUB-side, whereas the more recent API ( 3.2+ IIRC ) have moved into a PUB-side topic-filtering, where the mis-matched string conventions may cause troubles.

Comment: The code is functional. After running the Python Publisher-Python Subscriber and the C++ Publisher - C++ Subscriber test, I made an other try with the original code and it works just fine. The reason why? remained unclear to me.